# Number of solutions of $e^z=ez^3$ inside the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to show that the number of solutions of the equation $e^z=ez^3$ inside the unit circle
$S^1=\{|z|<1\}$ is $2$ (counted with multiplicities). I know how to prove in general that the equation $e^z=az^n$, for some $a>e$ has exactly $n$ zeroes inside $S^1$ using Rouchè' Theorem.

I have thought of two ways of proving this but I get stuck in both:

- Since the function $f(z)=e^z-ez^3$ does not have any poles, I can use the Argument Principle which, in this case, states that
  $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{f'(\zeta)}{f(\zeta)}d\zeta=N_{f}(0)\ ,$$
  where $N_{f}(0)$ denotes the number of zeroes of $f$ in $S^{1}$.
  My problem here is that I don't know how to compute this integral.
- The derivative of $f$ is $f'(z)=e^z-3ez^2$, which I know that it has $2$ zeroes in $S^1$. So if I prove that $f$ has the same number of zeroes with its derivative $f'$ then I am done. But I don't know how to prove this also.

Comment: Your $S^1$ would be the unit disc (or is it disk? I never remember), not the circle. Unit circle would refer to the set $|z| = 1$, aka the boundary of the disc.

Comment: Maybe defining a new function $g$ such that $f'+g=f$ and then use Rouche's Theorem?

Comment: what about taking some small $\delta>0$ and showing by Rouche that $e^z-ez^3$ has precisely three zeroes on $|z|<1+\delta$, one of them is clearly $1$ (and none other is on the unit circle) which implies the result letting $\delta \to 0$

Comment: @Conrad Nice idea! My problem with this approach is the application of Rouche to the bigger circle and in particular, how do I prove that $e^{1+\delta}<e(1+\delta)^3$?

Comment: @Robert I tried that but did not succeed!

Comment: use that $e^{\delta} \le 1+2\delta < (1+\delta)^3$ for $\delta >0$ small enough (the derivative at zero of $e^{\delta} -1-2\delta$ is negative and the function is zero, so it will be negative near by)

Comment: @Conrad That's great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the hint in comments by Conrad, choose $g(z)=e^z$ and $h(z)=ez^3$ so that  you have the inequality
$|g(z)|<|h(z)|$
$\implies ez^3-e^z>0$ 
Inside the circle $|z|=1+\delta$ where $\delta>0$, above inequality reduces to
$ (1+\delta)^3-e^{\delta}>0$ which can be proved using little calculus on the function $p(\delta)=(1+\delta)^3-e^\delta$.

> Observe that $p(0)=0$ and $p'(0)=2>0$ tells that $p(\delta)$ is increasing in the vicinity of zero. Using Rouche's theorem, as $h(z)$ has $3$ zeros counting multiplicities inside $|z|=1+\delta$,
> hence $g(z)+h(z)=f(z)$ too has $3$ zeros inside the same circle, one of them is at $z=1$ so you have exactly $2$ zeros inside the unit circle.

Comment: This proof is a bit sloppy to accept it as an answer (I think) since it does not add much more than the hint in the comments. For example, why the multiplicity of the root $1$ is $1$? Or, shouldn't we then take the limit $\delta\to 0$? Or $\delta$ should be choses small. Do you agree that it is a bit sloppy or do you think I should accept it?

Comment: @richarddedekind....$f(1)=0$ but $f'(1)\ne 0$ assures that $z=1$ is a simple root of $f(z)$.

Comment: I know, I am just saying that it does not add to the comment of Conrad.